# Loop in java until the users pushes enter

Tags: java

How do I loop in java until the user pushes enter, then stop?

Something like

```
while(System.in != ""){
  do x;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Are you planning to do something in the background while waiting for the user to press enter?

Comment: If you simply want the user to wait until the enter key is hit, you can simply do `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();`.

Comment: It will not work, this I/O is blocking.

Comment: No I need to run a function repeatedly until enter is pushed then stop.

Comment: I guess you'll either have to do those things in another thread or make a Swing application with an ActionListener.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
while (System.in.available() == 0) {
   // Do whatever you want
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to loop until the user presses enter without anything else, you will want something like the following (untested, but should be enough of a hint):

```
boolean blankLine = true;
loop:
while (true) {
    int available;
    while ((available = System.in.available()) == 0) {
        // Do something
    }
    do {
         switch (System.in.read()) {
             default:
                 blankLine = false;
                 break;
             case '\n':
                 if (blankLine)
                     break loop;
                 blankLine = true;
                 break;
         }
    } while (--available > 0);
}
```

Comment: Awesome.. I'll click answered in 5 minutes when it will let me.

Comment: Caution is advised! The javadoc says says this is an *estimate*: `Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream`

Comment: Well http://www.java.net/node/697124 seems to suggest this is the only way, and this estimate will never be greater than zero when the Enter key hasn't been pressed, as otherwise that will cause it to block. The only risk is that this would return zero when it shouldn't, but I highly doubt that (although if this ever doesn't work, that could be why).

Comment: I have a vague memory that this didn't work very well on Windows 9x or some such. (Not tried it any more recently than that.)

Comment: This will work and stop the loop by pressing other keys as well. What if i need it to stop when and only the user presses enter key?

Comment: @winux Please see my edit. Untested, likely needs tweaking, but hopefully gives you an idea for one way to implement this.

Comment: When you press enter key (\n) read function converts it to null terminator and doesn't include new line as part of the input string. Never tested it yet either.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.nextLine().length() != 0){
.....
}

use nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: @marscom is trying to loop until the enter gets hit. Could you check the comments section for the question?